# How to upload images to Firebase Storage using JAVAFX (java 8)

Tags: java, firebase, file-upload, fxml

I eed to save images in a web service (preferably Firebase Storage) using java (JAVAFX project)

I tried a lot of methods to save my images, on like Google Drive, Firebase Storage, Flickr.. and i haven't found any tutorial anywhere that is clearly understandable.. is there any other web service that i can use? or some clear tutorial on how to do it for Firebase with java?

here´s the dependency that i'm using in pom.xml, I've already managed to import all the necessary bookstores to the Firestore admin

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
        <artifactId>firebase-admin</artifactId>
        <version>6.8.1</version>
</dependency>
```

I already have the part of getting the user's image and showing it in an ImageView, but now I have no idea how to use the classes offered by Firestore admin to upload and get the download link

I've found a short block of code from another question and i the image shows how to upload, but i really don't know..

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62614014/firebase-storage-image-uploads-from-java-dont-show-thumbnail-preview-in-the-fir