# Firebase Storage image uploads from Java don't show thumbnail preview in the Firebase console

Tags: java, firebase, file-upload, firebase-storage, firebase-admin

i am trying to upload an image to firebase storage using java. The image is successfully uploaded but when you see it in the firebase it doesn't load ...

here is the code, is it correct?

```
FirebaseOptions options = FirebaseOptions.builder().setCredentials(
            GoogleCredentials.fromStream(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/credentials.json"))).setDatabaseUrl("https://myexample.firebaseio.com")
            .setStorageBucket("myexample-123456.appspot.com").build();

    FirebaseApp fireApp = FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);

    StorageClient storageClient = StorageClient.getInstance(fireApp);
    InputStream   testFile      = new FileInputStream(userSelection); // userselection is the image path that the user chose
    String        blobString    = "ProfilePictures/" + "TEST.png";

    storageClient.bucket().create(blobString, testFile, "image/png", Bucket.BlobWriteOption.userProject("myexample-123456"));
```

this is the result on google firebase, the image never loads
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a known issue that image previews don't display in the Firebase console when uploading from backend code.  It works fine if the file was uploaded from a Firebase client app.  It might also work if you have a Firebase client request a download URL, which would create the URL necessary for the preview.

I suggest filing a bug report with [Firebase support](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support).  This is a common request.

Comment: I'm using this `System.out.println(BlobInfo.newBuilder(blob.getBlobId()).setContentType("text/plain").build().getMediaLink());` to print the link of the image and it is printing null in the console.. wasn't it supposed to print the link?

Comment: There are several of ways to get a link to a file. The console does not try all of them.  As I said, this is a known issue, so reach out to Firebase support to add your voice.  If you have a new problem, please post it separately.